# c++ GMP mpz_init() causes Segmentation Fault 11

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, gmp

I have a program that receives a `Segmentation Fault 11` notice the simplicity of the `main`.  Here is my entire working script:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gmp.h"

void 
makeprime ()
{
    // *********************** VARIABLE DECLARATION *********************** //
    // initilize the variables as gmp class instances
    mpz_t l, rand;
    unsigned long seed;
    // perform inits to create variable pointers with 0 value
    mpz_inits(l, rand);
    //mpz_init(rand);

    // calculate the random number floor
    mpz_ui_pow_ui(l, 2, 199);

    // initilze the state object for the random generator functions
    gmp_randstate_t rstate;
    // initialize state for a Mersenne Twister algorithm. This algorithm is fast and has good randomness properties.
    gmp_randinit_mt(rstate);

    // create the generator seed for the random engine to reference 
    gmp_randseed_ui(rstate, seed);

    /*
    Function:
    int mpz_probab_prime_p (const mpz_t n, int reps)

    Determine whether n is prime. Return 2 if n is definitely prime, return 1 if n is probably prime (without being certain), 
    or return 0 if n is definitely composite.
    */
    do {
        // return a uniformly distributed random number in the range 0 to n-1, inclusive.
        mpz_urandomb(rand, rstate, 310);

        // add the random number to the low number, which will make sure the random number is between the low and high ranges
        mpz_add(rand, rand, l);

        gmp_printf("randomly generated number: %Zd\n", rand);

    } while ( !(mpz_probab_prime_p(rand, 25)) );        

    // *********************** GARBAGE COLLECTION *********************** //
    // empty the memory location for the random generator state
    gmp_randclear(rstate);
    // clear the memory locations for the variables used to avoid leaks
    mpz_clear(l);
    mpz_clear(rand);
}

int
main (void)
{
    makeprime();
    return 0;
}
```

Ok, now I'll add the following 2 lines at the beginning of main (not changing ANYTHING else about the script):

```
int
main (void)
{
    mpz_t r;      //added this line
    mpz_init (r); //and added this line

    makeprime();
    return 0; 
}
```

Now my program doesn't execute properly nor does it print or execute `makeprime()`, instead I get a `Segmentation Fault 11` notice.

What gives? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @Galik - I updated my OP to include the rest of my code

Comment: How about reading the manual for `mpz_inits`? (hint: "NULL-terminated")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to debug your code using `gdb` and it gave me a segfault at line `mpz_inits(l, rand)`. Then I modified that line and now it does not give a segfault. I will see if I can find a reason for the segfault.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gmp.h"

void 
makeprime ()
{
    // *********************** VARIABLE DECLARATION *********************** //
    // initilize the variables as gmp class instances
    mpz_t l, rand;
    unsigned long seed;
    // perform inits to create variable pointers with 0 value

    //mpz_inits(l, rand);
    mpz_init(rand);
    mpz_init(l);

    // calculate the random number floor
    mpz_ui_pow_ui(l, 2, 199);

    // initilze the state object for the random generator functions
    gmp_randstate_t rstate;
    // initialize state for a Mersenne Twister algorithm. This algorithm is fast and has good randomness properties.
    gmp_randinit_mt(rstate);

    // create the generator seed for the random engine to reference 
    gmp_randseed_ui(rstate, seed);

    /*
    Function:
    int mpz_probab_prime_p (const mpz_t n, int reps)

    Determine whether n is prime. Return 2 if n is definitely prime, return 1 if n is probably prime (without being certain), 
    or return 0 if n is definitely composite.
    */
    do {
        // return a uniformly distributed random number in the range 0 to n-1, inclusive.
        mpz_urandomb(rand, rstate, 310);

        // add the random number to the low number, which will make sure the random number is between the low and high ranges
        mpz_add(rand, rand, l);

        gmp_printf("randomly generated number: %Zd\n", rand);

    } while ( !(mpz_probab_prime_p(rand, 25)) );        

    // *********************** GARBAGE COLLECTION *********************** //
    // empty the memory location for the random generator state
    gmp_randclear(rstate);
    // clear the memory locations for the variables used to avoid leaks
    mpz_clear(l);
    mpz_clear(rand);
}

int
main (void)
{
    makeprime();
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I looked at the [GMP Documentation](https://gmplib.org/manual/Initializing-Integers.html) and it says the following about `mpz_inits`.

> — Function: void **mpz_init** (*mpz_t x*)
>
> Initialize x, and set its value to 0.
>
> — Function: void **mpz_inits** (*mpz_t x, ...*)
>
> Initialize a **NULL-terminated** list of mpz_t variables, and set their values to 0.

You must end the list of variables you want to initialize with `NULL`. So you need to replace `mpz_inits(l, rand)` with `mpz_inits(l, rand, NULL)` and it works just fine.

**EDIT:**

You forgot to initialize the seed. In the function `makeprime` you declare `unsigned long seed;` but do not assign a value to the seed hence you get the same numbers every time because the value of the seed is same for every execution.

Typically random seeds are initialized using the system time. You can use

```
seed = (int) time(NULL);
```

to initialize the seed just after the declaration. Everything works fine then (Don't forget to include `ctime` or `time.h`).

Comment: Ok, I made your suggested change, and yes.  The first code structure works fine without any problems.  But, when I add `mpz_t r;` and `mpz_init (r);` to my `main()` the `mpz_urandomb` doesn't seed properly anymore and generates the same number everytime the program is run.

Comment: @Galik I can't see any C++ in the code except for `#include <iostream>` which anyway is unused :-P

Comment: @LakshayGarg The question is tagged C++ and the entire code is C++. Whether or not you can get it to run through a C compiler does't mean it is not C++.

Comment: @LakshayGarg awesome.  This script is the first portion of an encryption program that I'm messing around with. I was under the impression that system time was a bad thing to seed off of because there is a possibility that the seed value could be guessed, and therefore the numbers could be regenerated - do you know true that is?  If it is indeed an issue, is there a different way I should be initializing the seed value rather than using ctime?

Comment: @sadmicrowave I'm not really sure because I haven't done this kind of work but if you are into it then this might be what you are looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator

Comment: @sadmicrowave You may want to accept this as an answer if you found it useful. Thanks

Comment: @LakshayGarg yea, I'll definitely accept it! Thanks so much for your help.  Here is a short reference to what I'm talking about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755482/random-number-generation-in-c-using-gmp